# Feign Client request params duplicating

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, feign

I'm using feign client to call REST endpoint(POST method) but I'm getting a bad request error. Below is the request.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/2.0/fo/report/?action=launch&template_id={template_id}&output_format=csv&hide_header=1&report_title={report_title}&use_tags=1&tag_set_by=name&tag_set_include={included_tags}")
String launchReport(@RequestHeader(X_REQUESTED_WITH) String curlSample, @RequestHeader("Cookie") String cookie, @RequestParam("template_id") String templateId, @RequestParam("report_title") String reportTitle, @RequestParam("included_tags") String includedTags);
```

Here cookie is the session header from a previous request. I need to set that for authentication.. So there are two RequestHeaders.. Below is the error,

```
feign.FeignException$BadRequest: [400 Bad Request] during [POST] to [https://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/2.0/fo/report/?action=launch&template_id=xxx&template_id=xxx&template_id=xxx&output_format=csv&hide_header=1&report_title=xxx&report_title=xxx&report_title=xxx&use_tags=1&tag_set_by=name&tag_set_include=xxx] [xxxClient#launchxxx(String,String,String,String,String)]: [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

I saw that parameters are duplicated in the request. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem today and fixed it by removing the placeholders in the URL at the mapping annotation

in this case this should work:

@PostMapping(value = "/api/2.0/fo/report/?action=launch&output_format=csv&hide_header=1&use_tags=1&tag_set_by=name")

Answer (score -1):

Using @PathVariable instead of @RequestParam solved the issue

Comment: That's a whole other story, it doesn't fix the issue, it's just a serious workaround and one might not be able to change the endpoint to have a path parameter instead of a request parameter